# How to get rid of isolated pixels in a raster using gdal, numpy functionalities in python ?

Tags: python, gdal, numpy

I have a raster which I got after passing it through a certain thresholding to map the debris cover pixels. However, there are certain isolated pixels here and there probably due to limitations in the imagery resolution. How do I get rid of these isolated pixels in a python environment using pure gdal and numpy functionalaties?

Comment: Maybe [gdal_sieve](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_sieve.html) could help?

Comment: Can you share an image showing what you currently have and what you would like the output to look like?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the responses. I figured out how to achieve this using erode and dialate function implemented in pygeotools (https://github.com/dshean/pygeotools). The function (mask_islands) resides in the malib library of pygeotools and is based on ndimage morphological package. Overall, pygeotools offers good resources for raster image processing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the image is a classification, you could use [gdal_sieve.py](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_sieve.html) to remove the isolated pixels. The *-st* option controls the minimum object size, so that objects larger than this threshold are not merged into neighbouring land cover classes.

Otherwise, if you are simply trying to remove 'noise' within an image, you might consider using a smoothing filter using a moving 3x3 or 5x5 window. Several filters are already implemented in [RSGISLib](http://www.rsgislib.org/rsgislib_imagefilter.html#smoothing-filters), and can be run within a Python script.

Another option is to segment the image, and then reclassify the isolated pixels based on the object size & reflectance values. The isolated pixels could be delineated using a simple [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) statement. This type of approach is described in the following paper:

*Clewley, D., Bunting, P., Shepherd, J., et al. (2014). A python-based open source system for geographic object-based image analysis (GEOBIA) utilizing raster attribute tables. Remote Sensing, 6 (7), 6111-6135.*